# Cant get right data from ABPersonViewController if there is linked contacts

Tags: ios, abpersonviewcontroller

I have a contact with linked contacts. So when I show this contact with ABPersonViewController is has original emails and emails from linked contacts.
[image]

When I select linked email (John-appleseed@mac.com) then delegate method calls:

```
- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    //get selected phone number
    ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
    CFIndex index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multi, identifier);
    NSString *selectedContactData = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, index);

    return NO;
}
```

But in selectedContactData I get not selected email, but first one.
I have this problem only with combined contacts.

Is there a proper way to choose email from contact with connected contacts?

Comment: Unrelated, but don't forget to `CFRelease(multi)`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can imagine the behavior you describe is that you might be referencing a `ABRecordRef` in some property or ivar that you populated when you first populated `displayedPerson` property for the `ABPersonViewController`. Clearly, in this code snippet you are correctly using the `person` property that was passed to this delegate method, but perhaps you simplified the code snippet when sharing it with us? When I use your code snippet with `shouldShowLinkedPeople` turned on, it works fine for me for a linked contact's properties.

If you're sure you don't have an issue with using the wrong `ABRecordRef` variable, the only other possibility I can imagine is that I have experienced strange behavior using the default contacts that are provided on the simulator. I might suggest trying this on an actual device with real linked contacts.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Looks like it a bug for ios7. On ios8 it works fine :)